# How can I specify the coordinates in a boxplot as black dots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxplot

How can I specify the coordinates (here outliers) as black dots? The color in the square brackets is already defined as black, if I insert "mark=*" in the square brackets the boxplots disappear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}
    [
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2},
    ymin={0},
    ymax={890000},
    ]
    \addplot+[color=black, 
    boxplot prepared={
            median=231040,
            upper quartile=307800,
            lower quartile=189576,
            upper whisker=568892,
            lower whisker=92821
    },
    ] coordinates {(1,790724)(1,603189)(1,574542)};

    \addplot+[color=black,  
    boxplot prepared={
      median=290626,
    lower whisker=97525,
    lower quartile=218151,
    upper quartile=379487,
    upper whisker=674757
    },
    ] coordinates {(3,835414)(3,752967)(3,737438)(3,737438)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From the duplicate: add `mark options={black}` to both `\addplot+` commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}
    [
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2},
    ymin={0},
    ymax={890000},
    ]
    \addplot+[color=black, 
      mark=*,
     mark options={black},
    boxplot prepared={
            median=231040,
            upper quartile=307800,
            lower quartile=189576,
            upper whisker=568892,
            lower whisker=92821
    },
    ] coordinates {(1,790724)(1,603189)(1,574542)};

    \addplot+[color=black,
     mark=*,
     mark options={black},
    boxplot prepared={
      median=290626,
    lower whisker=97525,
    lower quartile=218151,
    upper quartile=379487,
    upper whisker=674757
    },
    ] coordinates {(3,835414)(3,752967)(3,737438)(3,737438)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!